# Testing internet connection on iPad app using ios5

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I have been searching through the forum regarding how to check whether there is internet or not in my ipad app. I just created a simple webview project with other view controllers and I need to display a UIAlert message when the internet is not available. In my case it is displaying the message when I run the app. When I run the app with internet and then deactivate the internet, it does not show the UIAlert message, that is if I switch between the views, it does not any more show the no internet connection.

I have followed this way of implementation in my project: (sorry my mistake this is the link I followed) http://mozymac.com/forums/f54/how-check-if-there-internet-connection-iphone-os-devices-595/ [This is the new edited question]

Apart from that I went through some of the previous questions in Stackoverflow forum like for ex: [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

But everybody has their own version. If any one has a much more updated method for ios5, xcode 4.2.1 of how to accomplish this then would be helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you want to check for internet connection before actually trying to load a request in the `UIWebView`?

Best practice is to just start loading, and use your `UIWebViewDelegate`/`NURLConnectionDelegate` to inspect the NSError to see what is wrong. In case of network failure you will receive an error with a domain equal to  `NSURLErrorDomain`. The error code will indicate what the problem is, see  the `NSError codes` enum.

And only after the first error start your reachability to see when the internet connection becomes available again. Or easier, just let the user retry.

Using the `Reachability` code will actually cause some overhead. It takes time to check if the internet is available, which you could just have used to set up the actual connection as well.

**Example**

Since you are using a `UIWebView` you should implement the following delegate method to be notified of errors.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (![[error domain] isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]) {
        // not a nsurl error, take other appropriate action
        return;
    }

    NSInteger code = [error code];
    // show appropriate error to user, based on code
}
```

In this delegate method you should do whatever is needed to achieve what you want. You could retry the request yourself, show a message to the user or start listening for reachability changes using the code from the Reachability example provided by Apple.

Comment: thanks for your reply, is it possible to provide a sample code of how to use this for better understanding

Comment: Thanks Joris for providing an example

Answer (score 1):

Apple has one, it's called Reachability. Here's the link to it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Following blog link also based on the aforesaid link .... http://developmobilesoftware.blogspot.in/2013/07/check-whether-ios-device-is-connected.html

Answer (score 1):

Best way to check internet connection is Reachibility application

[link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Or else

```
+ (BOOL)isNetworkAvailable
{
    CFNetDiagnosticRef diag;        
    diag = CFNetDiagnosticCreateWithURL (NULL, (CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.apple.com"]);

    CFNetDiagnosticStatus status;
    status = CFNetDiagnosticCopyNetworkStatusPassively (diag, NULL);        

    CFRelease (diag);

    if ( status == kCFNetDiagnosticConnectionUp )
    {
        //NSLog (@"Connection is up");
        return YES;
    } else {
        NSLog (@"Connection is down");
        return NO;
    }
}
```